# CSS margin not being applied as expected

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

[image]

As you can see, the Avatar has a width wider than I want. I have tried setting the `margin-right` and the `width`, but neither seem to work.

**Question**

How do I reduce the width of the column?

Comment: thats not margin, the margin is colored when you hover it, its the acutal size cause the .col class takes up 100%, try setting the .col-person-avatar to a fixed with (160.44 px in this case) unless you need it to be percentage 
.col-person-avatar {
 width:160.44px;
}

Comment: Hi subkonskrukt, thanks. When I set the width to 37px or less it seems to collapse down. That works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is `padding` not `margin`. That element does not has any given `margin`. The green color you see on browser is `padding`.

```
.col.col-person-avtar {
 padding-right: 0;
}
```

if you check see the code, `col` class already has `margin:0` given, hence there is no `margin`

If that does not work, try giving it `!important;`

```
.col-person-avtar {
 padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

And still if this does not meet your requirements try this below code.

```
.col-person-avtar {
 width: calc(100% - 15px) !important;
}
```

this `15px` can be altered to whatever value you want, try modifying it till you get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, but unfortunately `padding-right: 0;` has no effect.

Comment: did you try giving it `!important` ? like `padding-right: 0 !important;` ?

Comment: @Richard updated my answer for multiple possible solutions.

Comment: The width attribute fixed it, thanks. The width has to below 37px.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.col-person-avatar {
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

To

```
.col-person-avatar {
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

here, **!important** will overwrite existing classes which is available somewhere in your project.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it's the excess space in the blue area you want to remove then you will have to reduce the width of the previous div or removing  width:100% from .col should do the trick.

If you want to remove the space in the green area then remove padding. :)